# conditionally add rows to data frames in a list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, nested, conditional-statements

I have a list of data frames, where each data frame has either 1 or 2 rows named "mis" or "syn" (form a column named cat) and a second col with a numeric frequency. I want to fill in each data frame such that if the "mis" row is missing, it adds a mis row with frequency = 0
and if "syn" row is missing, is adds a syn row with frequency 1:

```
###exmaple: 
#example list of dataframes:
df1<- as.data.frame(cbind(cat = c("mis", "syn"), freq= c(4, 2)))
df2<- as.data.frame(cbind(cat = "mis", freq= 1))
df3<- as.data.frame(cbind(cat = "syn", freq= 2))
df_list<- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3= df3)
```

looks like:

```
> df_list
$df1
cat freq
1 mis    4
2 syn    2

$df2
cat freq
1 mis    1

$df3
cat freq
1 syn    2
```

Expected output:

```
> df_list
$df1
cat freq
mis    4
syn    2

$df2
cat freq
mis    1
syn    1

$df3
cat freq
syn    2
mis    0
```

what I've tried:
first I change the row names so that I can search by them

```
df_list_named<- lapply(df_list, function(x){ row.names(x)<-as.character(x$cat); x})

df_list_named
$df1
cat freq
mis mis    4
syn syn    2

$df2
cat freq
mis mis    1

$df3
cat freq
syn syn    2
```

then I've been trying to use an ifelse loop to append the rows to the the dataframes where it needs it, but I can't get it to work:

```
test<- lapply(df_list_named, function (x) ifelse(!row.names(df_list_named[[x]]) %in% "mis", rbind(df_list_named[[x]], c(cat = "mis", freq= 0)), 
                                                                                               ifelse(!row.names(df_list_named[[x]]) %in% "syn", rbind(df_list_named[[x]], c(cat = "syn", freq= 1))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with `lapply`

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) {
   if(all(c("mis", "syn") %in% x$cat))
      x
   else if("mis" %in% x$cat)
      rbind(x, data.frame(cat = "syn", freq = 1))
   else
      rbind(x, data.frame(cat = "mis", freq = 0))
})

#$df1
#  cat freq
#1 mis    4
#2 syn    2

#$df2
#  cat freq
#1 mis    1
#2 syn    1

#$df3
#  cat freq
#1 syn    2
#2 mis    0
```

**data**

```
df1<- data.frame(cat = c("mis", "syn"), freq= c(4, 2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2<- data.frame(cat = "mis", freq= 1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df3<- data.frame(cat = "syn", freq= 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df_list<- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3= df3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `"base"`  data frame, `merge` it with all data frames in the list using `Map`. The `duplicated` rows created in the already complete data frames can be safely excluded with `!`, as they are always placed at the end.

```
(base <- data.frame(cat=factor(c("syn", "mis")), freq=factor(1:0)))
#   cat freq
# 1 syn    1
# 2 mis    0

Map(function(x) {y <- (merge(x, base, all=TRUE));y[!duplicated(y$cat), ]}, df_list)
# $df1
#   cat freq
# 1 mis    4
# 3 syn    2
# 
# $df2
#   cat freq
# 1 mis    1
# 3 syn    1
# 
# $df3
#   cat freq
# 1 syn    2
# 3 mis    0
```

#### Data

```
df_list <- list(df1 = structure(list(cat = structure(1:2, .Label = c("mis", 
"syn"), class = "factor"), freq = structure(2:1, .Label = c("2", 
"4"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)), df2 = structure(list(cat = structure(c(cat = 1L), .Label = "mis", class = "factor"), 
    freq = structure(c(freq = 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), df3 = structure(list(cat = structure(c(cat = 1L), .Label = "syn", class = "factor"), 
    freq = structure(c(freq = 1L), .Label = "2", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)))
```

Comment: for some reason when I run this exactly, I get a total replacement of all dfs to "base" (with freq. 1 or 0)

Comment: @MycoP Weird, I exactly used your data, though (added now). Have you tried a fresh R session?